# Can't retrieve attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, console.log

I have the following click function.

```
$(".charPortait").on("click", function(event){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

The log says "undefined." To find out why it may not be getting the value, I tried this next:

```
$(".charPortait").on("click", function(event){
    console.log(this);
});
```

this logs:

```
<div id="TomiasPortrait" class="col charPortait" value="Tomias">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

I don't understand why I am not getting the attribute "value" to log properly.

Comment: `value` is a non-standard attribute on a div element, so perhaps it doesn't map to the `.value` property. Have you tried using a `data-value` attribute instead, and getting the value with `this.getAttribute('data-value')`? Why are you binding a click handler to a div? If the user doesn't have a mouse or other pointing device they won't be able to use your page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".charPortait").on("click", function(event){
    console.log($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="TomiasPortrait" class="col charPortait" value="Tomias">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Div has not value.
2. Use `data-*`
3. Get the value using `.attr(data-*)`

```js
$(".charPortait").on("click", function(event){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TomiasPortrait" class="col charPortait" data-value="Tomias">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute for getting the value. please check below example will work for you.

```
<div id="TomiasPortrait" class="col charPortait" data-value="Tomias">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".charPortait").on("click", function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The log says "undefined." because it indicates that a variable has not been assigned a value.

So you have to use `attr()` to get the value of that attribute. In your `HTML`, there is no `value` attribute so you can use `data-` then concatenate your data name. See below.

```js
$(".charPortait").on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="TomiasPortrait" class="col charPortait" data-value="Tomias">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(".charPortait").on("click", function(event){
    console.log($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TomiasPortrait" class="col charPortait" value="Tomias">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.